# How to check the “System Spec” in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: specifications, ubuntu-11.04

I am total noob in Linux. I wanna know what is the equivalent of "My Computer" in Ubuntu 11.04. I want to check my computer specs such as Processor Speed, Memory, and etc. Whenever I check properties in Home Folder it only gives me the HD capacity... I also tried looking at System Settings but I can't find it there. Please help...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that questions on _using_ computers are better suited for other sites of StackExchange - you may be interested in http://askubuntu.com/ . Wait a minute ... [did you already ask it there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-to-check-the-system-spec-in-ubuntu-11-04)?

Answer (score 11):

There are various GUI applications to do the tasks you want, but they're almost always less detailed, and are unnecessary fluff.

Processor clock frequency (along with features, model, etc.)

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Memory

```
free -m
```

Mounted file system sizes; total, used and free

```
df -h
```

Answer (score 2):

1. click Dash home button on ur home screen
2. select more apps
3. select system info
4. in "overview tab" you can see very brief summary (e.g. Clock speed, RAM, and HD size.